# Получение результатов update в ORM

Tags: php, sql, orm, update

Есть запросы через ORM

```
 $insert_profile = ORM::for_table('profiles') 
   -> raw_query($sql);
```

и

```
 $update_card = ORM::for_table('cards') 
   -> raw_query($sql);
```

Как понятно по названию один на `update`,а другой на `insert` таблиц. sql-строка с запросом (он каждый раз разный, сейчас просто выжрал из контекста чтобы лишнего не болталось).
Вопрос. Как понять из переменных `$insert_profile` и `$update_card`, что запросы успешны?

Comment: Вы не понимаете, для чего нужен ORM и неправильно его используете.

Comment: Как правило ORM библиотеки что-то возвращают при разных манипуляциях с базой данных. Например, при *INSERT* новый ID в таблице, при *UPDATE* флаг `true` или `false`. Смотрите в документации библиотеки, которую Вы используете.

Comment: @zhenyab спасибо за нормальный ответ=)

Comment: @zhenyab, при удачном инсерте вернет ид,а если неудачный? false или null?

Comment: К сожалению Idiorm в документации не указывает что возвращается в случае неудачи. Скорее всего *null*, так как объект не создается, но лучше проверить эмпирическим путем.

Comment: Заглянул в исходники. В случае с raw_query и for_table Вы просто получаете инициализированный класс с соединением к базе данных, независимо ни от чего. Таким образом, если Вам нужен более специфичный ответ на запрос, используйте специализированные функции, либо переходите на более серьезную ORM

Comment: @zhenyab, в проекте походу используется симфони.во всяком случае в папке с либами валяется папка с симфони...я решил делать на orm  полностью $up_profile=ORM::factory('profiles', $profile_id)->values($sql)->save();

Comment: Это очень правильное решение. Но как правило в ORM крайне редко используется чистый SQL, а работают с моделями, которые создает ORM.

Comment: @zhenyab,просто привык работать с нативом-а тут в проекте орм.сложно немного перестроиться