# Краш апача при вставке в ORM'е

Tags: php, orm, update

есть запрос

```js
$in_card=ORM::factory('cards')
  ->values($sql)
  ->save();
```

и на этом запросе у меня крашиться апач.
массив данных полный (исключая id-автоинкремент он).

Выкидывал в лог что происходит,полный код

```js
 while($timeout<10){
      /*считывание переменных,с ними все в порядке-не раз проверил*/
      $date_to_up=date('Y-m-d h:m:s');
      $sql=array();
      $this->log->addError($sql['is_activated']='1');
      $this->log->addError($sql['is_blocked']='0');
      $this->log->addError($sql['client_id']=$client_id);
      $this->log->addError($sql['profile_id']='0');
      $this->log->addError($sql['uid']=$uid);
      $this->log->addError($sql['balance']=$balance);
      if(!empty($expires_at))
        $this->log->addError ($sql['expires_at']=$expires_at);
      else 
        $this->log->addError ($sql['expires_at']='0000-00-00 00:00:00');
      if(!empty($created_at))
        $this->log->addError ($sql['created_at']=$created_at);
      else 
        $this->log->addError ($sql['created_at']='0000-00-00 00:00:00');
      $this->log->addError ($sql['updated_at']=$date_to_up);
      $this->log->addError($sql['start_bonus_added']=$start_bonus_added);

      $this->log->addError("into ORM-query");  
      $in_card=ORM::factory('cards')
        ->values($sql)
        ->save();
      $this->log->addError("out ORM-query");
      $i++;
     $time_now=time();
     $timeout=$time_now-$time_start;
     if($size_table==$i){
       exit;
       }
    }
```

до краша апача в лог успевает написать следующее

```js
[2015-08-11 09:37:15] app.ERROR: 1 [] []
[2015-08-11 09:37:15] app.ERROR: 0 [] []
[2015-08-11 09:37:15] app.ERROR: 4 [] []
[2015-08-11 09:37:15] app.ERROR: 0 [] []
[2015-08-11 09:37:15] app.ERROR: zzzzzzzzzzzzz01 [] []
[2015-08-11 09:37:15] app.ERROR: 784 [] []
[2015-08-11 09:37:15] app.ERROR: 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [] []
[2015-08-11 09:37:15] app.ERROR: 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [] []
[2015-08-11 09:37:15] app.ERROR: 2015-08-11 09:08:15 [] []
[2015-08-11 09:37:15] app.ERROR: 627 [] []
[2015-08-11 09:37:15] app.ERROR: into ORM-query [] []
```

Он почему то не хочет выполнять запрос,хотя все данные нормальные поставляю.
Люди,есть идеи?

@zhenyab,помоги!!!!!=)

По заказу ворона)

```js
CREATE TABLE `cards` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `is_activated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `is_blocked` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `profile_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `balance` float NOT NULL,
  `expires_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_bonus_added` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `is_activated` (`is_activated`),
  KEY `client_id` (`client_id`),
  KEY `profile_id` (`profile_id`),
  KEY `is_blocked` (`is_blocked`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24664 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Куча `$this->log->addError()` не нужна, достаточно объявить массив и вывести его, например, через `$this->log->addError(var_export($sql, true))`. Не плохо бы показать `SHOW CREATE TABLE cards`. И "крашиться апач" - это падает апач и он больше не отвечает? Что-то мне подсказывает, что просто возникает ошибка (которую скорее всего можно посмотреть в логах апача) и скрипт перестает выполняться, но апач при этом продолжает работать

Comment: @BOPOH 1)работаю локально,и при попытке выполнить скрипт выскакивает окно о закрытии апача,его закрываешь и через 2 секунды еще раз выскакивает,в логе видно что перед первым крашем и вторым доходит до запроса и все,амба. 2)шоу включу в пост

Comment: а у Вас `$sql` пуст, к тому же при работе с ORM используйте сеттеры и гетеры

Comment: Нужно попробовать сделать все без *while*. Сдается мне что в этом кроется проблема. Один раз сохраняет?

Comment: @zhenyab,поменял фактри на фор_табле=заработало..я уже схожу с ума от этого орм.... можете подсказать почему подобный запрос возвращает только "1" $in_card=ORM::for_table('cards')->create()->set($sql)->save(); ,а id достать не получается-оно пустое( $in_card->id)

Comment: 1. Вы неправильно используете ORM. В корне подход неверный.
2. Этот ORM довольно примитивный и у него нет большого набора фич и особо не разбежишься. Я бы предложил почитать литературу по ООП, а потом по ORM. Это прольет свет на многие вопросы, которые для Вас непонятны в настоящее время.

Comment: @zhenyab. просто тут -http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/440425/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-update-%D0%B2-orm?noredirect=1#comment-462726- вы говорили что при инсерте получается ид,а там только true/false)

Comment: Я сказал, что это зависит от библиотеки, которая используется. Idiorm возвращает самого себя просто напросто независимо ни от чего. Я не изучал эту библиотеку основательно, но возможно там есть функция, которая собственно возвращает результат запроса. Но я в этом сомневаюсь. Есть другие, более богатые по набору инструментов библиотеки. Doctrine, например. Тем более Вы говорили, что в проекте фигурирует Symfony.

Comment: @zhenyab,таки идиорм там)))а сегодня можно сказать довел её до инфаркта и она призналась кто она,а симфони походу от первой версии проекта валяется=D